# How to automatically run a third party Windows 10 Store App on Windows-Start-Up after log in

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

What I want to achieve is: To run a third party Windows 10 Store App, after a user logged in into his Windows 10.

I've discovered already how to start “Bing News” Store app at start up after user logged in 3 steps. Thanks to [instantfundas](http://www.instantfundas.com/2012/12/how-to-run-modern-uimetro-apps-at.html).

Shortly explained the 3 steps:
1: Locate in Windows Registry - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes[app-name]
and check if it contains a “URL Protocol” in the format “URL:appname”.
*for example: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\bingnews*

2: Create a Shortcut on the desktop to that app: %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" "App's URL Protocol name:"
*for example: %windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c start "" "bingnews:"*

3: Copy the Shortcut into the startup folder:
C:\Users{the user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Unfortunately, the third party apps are not shown in this Windows Registry...
*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes*

I want to start the third party app Nu.nl

(I know about Kiosk mode, but this is not the solution I want to end up.)

Anybody any ideas?

Comment: WIndows Store apps are stored on c:\\(user)\appdata\local\\(app folder), you can perfectly add to the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run an entry pointing to the .exe file of the app

Comment: Store apps are located at: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps This location is hard to get permissions on... But when I do... I got the error that Apps must run inside a container...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- Open File Explorer
- In the file address bar type shell:AppsFolder.
- This will show all apps installed on your PC. Right click one of them and select "create Shortcut".
- It will create a shortcut on the the desktop.
- Finally copy the shortcut to the startup folder.

Comment: By the way, a quick way to access the startup folder : Press Win + R and type "shell:startup".